# How can a low-level wizard prevent damage to his spellbook?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard

A low-level wizard is usually too poor to have backup copies of his spellbook, so keeping his lone, precious spellbook safe early on *must* be a priority, but how does a low-level wizard do that? Assuming the wizard lugs around his spellbook, what's the best and least expensive way to protect that spellbook for a low-level wizard who will invariably suffer all the perils of adventuring life (like, for instance, swimming and *fireballs*)?

Comment: However he wants. Primarily opinion-based; There are too many possible answers to this question, and which ones are "best" depend entirely on what sort of campaign you're playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Protecting against accidental damage

The main threat to a spellbook is it being targeted on purpose. It's unlikely to be destroyed accidentally [because](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#table-dcs-break-burst-items):

> Unless the descriptive text for a spell (or attack) specifies otherwise, all items carried or worn by a creature are assumed to survive a magical attack.

Even if you roll a 1, only exposed items will be harmed by the attack.

To avoid water damage, put it in a [waterproof bag](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/containers-bags-boxes-more#table-bags-boxes).

## Protecting against intentional damage

Since you are asking about 0th level spells, I assume you're very low level and advanced, powerful magic is beyond you. So I'll focus on mundane solutions:

- [Extra spellbooks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/books-paper-writing-supplies#TOC-Spellbook) are 15/50/5gp and 3/1/1 pounds, so you can buy a bunch of extras. Write bogus magic doodles in your fake ones so someone not trained in spellcraft won't know it's a fake. If you're extra clever, give your real spellbook to the fighter.
- Alternatively, fill the first few pages with crap (to deter thieves trained in spellcraft) and write real spells on a couple of pages inside.
- Buy a [book lariat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/books-paper-writing-supplies#TOC-Spellbook) to avoid dropping the book or having it snatched away from you.
- [Tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/tattooed-spellbook) your spellbook on yourself. Or the fighter - the feat doesn't say you have to use your own body!